# Keystone rust bindings error when assembling "syscall; ret" shellcode

Tags: assembly

I'm working on a project related to Process Injection for learning Rust. I have to inject shellcode at some points and use the Keystone engine for assembling shellcode from source.

I detected that the rust bindings were not successful assembling `syscall; ret` shellcode.

I then tried to reproduce by creating a python and rust minimal version and ensuring the syntax in use was the same for both version (also both bindings has the same major and minor versions, which is v0.9)

**Python version:**

```
from keystone import *
from capstone import *

code = "syscall; ret"

ks = Ks(KS_ARCH_X86, KS_MODE_64)
ks.syntax = KS_OPT_SYNTAX_INTEL
encoding, count = ks.asm(code)

cs = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64)
disass = cs.disasm(bytes(encoding), 0x1000)

print("Assembly: %s" % code)
print("Binary: %s" % encoding)
print("Disassembly:")
for i in disass:
    print("0x%x:\t%s\t%s" % (i.address, i.mnemonic, i.op_str))
```

**Rust version:**

```
use keystone::{self, MODE_64};
use capstone::{self, prelude::BuildsCapstone};

fn main() {
    let code = "syscall; ret";

    let ks = keystone::Keystone::new(keystone::Arch::X86, MODE_64).unwrap();
    ks.option(keystone::OptionType::SYNTAX, keystone::OPT_SYNTAX_INTEL).unwrap();

    let encoding = ks.asm(code.to_string(), 0x1000).unwrap();

    let cs = capstone::Capstone::new()
                .x86()
                .mode(capstone::arch::x86::ArchMode::Mode64)
                .build().unwrap();
    
    let insns = cs.disasm_all(&encoding.bytes, 0x1000).unwrap();
    println!("Assembly: {}", code);
    println!("Binary: {:?}", encoding.bytes);
    println!("Disassembly:");
    for i in insns.iter() {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Here is the result of running the programs:
[image: Testing of both programs]

As you can see, the Rust implementation outputs random binary code and I would like to know why.

Is it related to a misunderstanding of rust ? or of the rust bindings ?
A bug in the rust bindings ?

I'm kinda stuck in my comprehension of the problem so if anyone can help me.

Regards.

Comment: C:\>python -c "from keystone import *;print(Ks(KS_ARCH_X86 , KS_MODE_64).asm(b'syscall;ret')")
([15, 5, 195], 2) =>0x0f0x050xc3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the `keystone` crate available on [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/keystone) - It runs with the version 0.9.0 and hasn't been updated for a while. It also has a few bugs which have now been fixed in 0.9.2.

You can use an unofficial binding like [this](https://github.com/impalabs/keystone-bindings) which is getting updates.
Or you can use the ones https://github.com/keystone-engine/keystone/tree/master/bindings/rust with your project where it'll build the latest compatible binding with `cmake`

Answer (score 2):

Cmake Version

```
D:\>cmake --version
cmake version 3.28.0-rc3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

rust version

```
D:\>cargo -V
cargo 1.73.0 (9c4383fb5 2023-08-26)
```

1. create a project directory  md dir
2. init the project in the directory  with cargo init
3. add the Dependency "keystone-engine" to Cargo.toml with cargo add

---

```
D:\>md rustkey

D:\>cd rustkey

D:\rustkey>cargo init
     Created binary (application) package

D:\rustkey>cargo add keystone-engine
    Updating crates.io index
      Adding keystone-engine v0.1.0 to dependencies.
             Features:
             + build-from-src
             + cmake
             - pkg-config
             - use-system-lib
    Updating crates.io index
```

source to compile

```
D:\rustkey>cd src

D:\rustkey\src>notepad main.rs

D:\rustkey\src>type main.rs
use keystone_engine::*;
fn main() {
        let engine = Keystone::new(Arch::X86, Mode::MODE_64).expect("Could not initialize Keystone engine");
        let result = engine.asm("syscall;ret".to_string(),0).expect("Could Not Assemble");
        println!("{}",result);
}

D:\rustkey\src>cd ..
```

build the project

```
D:\rustkey>cargo build
   Compiling cc v1.0.83
   Compiling libc v0.2.149
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling cmake v0.1.50
   Compiling keystone-engine v0.1.0
   Compiling rustkey v0.1.0 (D:\rustkey)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 5m 49s
```

running the project multiple times

```
    D:\rustkey>cargo -q run
0f05c3

D:\rustkey>cargo -q run
0f05c3

D:\rustkey>cargo -q run
0f05c3

D:\rustkey>cargo -q run
0f05c3
```

Comment: `keystone-engine` is the unofficial bindings I recommended in my answer as well. https://github.com/impalabs/keystone-bindings